# I need my display variable to be updated. Now it is resetting to null list

Tags: python, for-loop, variables, while-loop

```
while test_list != display:
 display=[] 
 guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
 for letter in chosen_word:
  
  if letter == guess:
      display+=[letter]  
  else:
      display+=["_"] 
 print(display)

Display variable is resetting to null
```

This code is part of hangman game. So the letter inputted by the user is checked for match with the word and it prints out a list with underscores and along with the correct guess in each position.
However, when i input another word the display variable is resetting to null list. I want it to be updated by the code.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is because you are creating a new `display` list on every iteration of your loop without saving your old list somewhere.

a solution is to save your old list in a variable, let's call it `old_display`, then we can check if that letter was already picked.

```py
old_display = []
while test_list != display:
    display = []
    guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
    for letter in chosen_word:

        if letter == guess:
            display += [letter]
        elif letter in old_display:  # check what was picked before
            display += [letter]
        else:
            display += ["_"]
    old_display = display  # update the old list to be the new list
    print(old_display)
```